# Why is assigning to a member of a pointer still valid after the pointer is moved?

Tags: rust

Why is `n1_mut` still valid in this example? It has been moved into `Option::Some` so shouldn't it be invalid?

```
struct MyRecordRec2<'a> {
    pub id: u32,
    pub name: &'a str,
    pub next: Box<Option<MyRecordRec2<'a>>>
}

#[test]
fn creating_circular_recursive_data_structure() {
    let mut n1_mut = MyRecordRec2 {
        id: 1,
        name: "n1",
        next: Box::new(None)
    };

    let n2 = MyRecordRec2 {
        id: 2,
        name: "n2",
        next: Box::new(Some(n1_mut))
    };

    //Why is n1_mut still valid?
    n1_mut.next = Box::new(Some(n2));
}
```

The following does not compile with the familiar "use of moved value"  error:

```
#[test]
fn creating_and_freezing_circular_recursive_data_structure() {
    let loop_entry = {
        let mut n1_mut = MyRecordRec2 {
            id: 1,
            name: "n1",
            next: Box::new(None),
        };

        let n2 = MyRecordRec2 {
            id: 2,
            name: "n2",
            next: Box::new(Some(n1_mut)),
        };

        n1_mut.next = Box::new(Some(n2));

        n1_mut
    };
}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `n1_mut`
  --> src/main.rs:44:9
   |
39 |             next: Box::new(Some(n1_mut)),
   |                                 ------ value moved here
...
44 |         n1_mut
   |         ^^^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `n1_mut` has type `MyRecordRec2<'_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Comment: Interesting. Not sure if this counts as a bug -- I don't think you can induce unsafety because there's no way to read the memory afterwards. But if you keep a raw pointer to the stack you can tell that `n1Mut.next` does indeed get set: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d41422bfd142c289667e7c2fb3183be0&version=undefined

Comment: Interestingly, it's not possible to even use `n1_mut.next` after. Also, adding a `Drop` implementation causes: "error[E0383]: partial reinitialization of uninitialized structure `n1_mut`"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with being a pointer or not; this works as well:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct NonCopy;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Example {
    name: NonCopy,
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Example {
        name: NonCopy,
    };

    drop(foo);

    foo.name = NonCopy;
}
```

Although I can't find the similar SO question that I know I've seen before, this [quote from nikomatsakis](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/modifying-a-moved-field/724/6) describes it:

> In general moves are tracked at a pretty narrow level of granularity. We intend to eventually permit you to "fill" both fields back in and then use the structure again. I guess that doesn't work today. I have to go look again at the moves code, but I think in general one of the things I'd like to pursue post 1.0 is extending the type system to deal better with things that have been moved from (in particular I want to support moves out of &mut pointers, so long as you restore the value before doing anything fallible). Anyway I think this example more-or-less falls out of treating things in a general way, though you could imagine rules that say "if you move f, you can never again touch any subfields of f without restoring f as a unit".

There's also discussion on [the Rust subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/5rkquz/why_can_we_assign_to_a_field_of_an_instance_of_a/?ref=share&ref_source=link), which links to Rust [issue 21232: "borrow-checker allows partial reinit of struct that has been moved away, but no use of it"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21232)

Conceptually, there's a flag for each of the fields in a struct in addition to the struct itself — I like to think of [Chris Morgan's cardboard box analogy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32238327/155423). You can move out of an owned struct's field so long as you move back in before using the struct:

```
drop(foo.name);
foo.name = NonCopy;

println!("{:?}", foo);
```

Evidently, since 2014, no one has bothered to put in the effort to enable marking the entire struct as valid again once the fields are re-filled.

Realistically, you don't really need this functionality as you can just assign the entire variable at once. The current implementation is overly-safe as Rust is preventing you from doing something that seems OK.